# React Leaflet Legend with MapContainer

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, legend

Good morning I know there is a duplicate but the proposed solution does not work, I would like to put a simple Legend with MapContainer, can you give an you give me a hand, to make the legend component with react leaflet 3.x?

Versionn React-Leaflet 3.1.0
This is my map

```
<MapContainer
    style={{ height: 480, width: "97.5%" }}
    zoom={2}
    center={[30.09, 51.505]}
    scrollWheelZoom={false}
    fadeAnimation={true}
    markerZoomAnimation={true}
  >
    <TileLayer
      url={urlLayer}
      test="http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <Legend />
    <CircleMarker
      center={[51.505, -0.09]}
      color={"#000000"}
      fillColor={"#FDD876"}
      stroke={true}
      fillOpacity={true}
      weight={1}
    >
      <Popup>
        A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
      </Popup>
    </CircleMarker>

   </MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I insert whenCreated with hooks of map

```
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
<MapContainer
    style={{ height: 480, width: "97.5%" }}
    zoom={2}
    center={[30.09, 51.505]}
    scrollWheelZoom={false}
    fadeAnimation={true}
    markerZoomAnimation={true}
    whenCreated={setMap}
  >
```

Legend

```
import L from "leaflet";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import './LegendComponent.css'
function Legend({ map }) {
  console.log(map);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      const legend = L.control({ position: "bottomright" });

      legend.onAdd = () => {
        const div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info legend");
        div.innerHTML =
          "<h4>This is the legend</h4>" +
          "<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing</b>";
        return div;
      };

      legend.addTo(map);
    }
  }, [map]); //here add map
  return null;
}

export default Legend;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add a legend in the @Giacomo example, but in a react-leaflet v2 class is:

```
class Legend extends MapControl {
    createLeafletElement(props) { }
    componentDidMount() {
        const legend = L.control({ position: "bottomleft" })

        legend.onAdd = () => {
            const QuadroLegenda = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info legend")
            let legendas = []
            legendas.push(
              '<iframe width="750" height="122" src="https://<my_server>/geoserver/<my_city>/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0 \
            &FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=esgoto \
            &LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceRule:True;fontName:Arial;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontColor:0x000000;fontSize:8;columns:6;rows:4;bgColor:0xFFFFFF;borderColor:000000;border:true;dpi:180;dx:0.2;dy:0.2;mx:0.2;my:0.2" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
            )
        QuadroLegenda.innerHTML = legendas.join()
        return QuadroLegenda
    }
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet
    legend.addTo(map)
}
```

}